# overridden onRequestPermissionResult function is not called

Tags: kotlin

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(requireContext(), Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(requireActivity(), arrayOf(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS), 1)
        } else {
            loadContacts()
        }
```

After ActivityCompat.requestPermissions function, overridden onRequestPermissionResult function has to be called. But, it isn't. I think another onRequestPermissionResult functin is called. How can I fix it?

Comment: This is not enough information to answer this question, unless somebody - by chance - knows this framework from the little you have provided. Please explain how your onRequestPermissionResult function should be called. Why do you expect this to happen? Which framework are you using (if any)? Is this self written code, or are these classes from an API/framework?